# Update manyToOne relationship typeorm entity

Tags: javascript, typeorm

Im trying to update an User entity which has a one to many relationship with Company. Ther user entity has a company id (companyId). As i see it now, the user entity needs to be stored first and then the user needs no be added to the company entity.

User entity:

```
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToOne, JoinColumn, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { PasswordTransformer } from './password.transformer';
import { Company } from "../company/company.entity";

@Entity({
  name: 'users',
})
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 255 })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ length: 255 })
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ length: 255 })
  email: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => Company, company => company.users)
  company: Company

  @Column({
    name: 'password',
    length: 255,
    transformer: new PasswordTransformer(),
  })
  @Exclude()
  password: string;
}

export class UserFillableFields {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  password: string;
  companyId: number;
}
```

Company entity:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToOne, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { UserFillableFields, User } from "../user/user.entity";

@Entity({
  name: 'company',
})
export class Company {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 255 })
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(type => User, user => user.company, { cascade: ['insert', 'update'] })
  users: User[];
}

export class CompanyFillableFields {
  name: string; 
  users: any
}
```

I get the error: `EntityColumnNotFound: No entity column "users" was found.`. What am i doing wrong?